# example of a function from interval notation

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Is it possible to get a function from a domain of [1,infinity) and a range of (-2,infinity)? If so can someone provide an example of one or a graph?
I did not think so because I thought that no matter what y value you had for x=1 then you could still get closer to -2, while not being -2.

Comment: By function you mean probably 'continuous or even cont.derivable? In either case, it surely exists. Just pinpoint an arbitrary (starting) value"$f(1)$ somewhere in the interval  $(-2,\infty)$, and when you start drawing the function, just let it oscilate (so you go smoothly up and down), s.t.:

-The first oscillation down comes to its (lowest) y-point at-1,9, the second one at-1,99; the third one at-1,999, etc.. 
- The oscillations up increase constatly (let's say by +1) with respect to the previous oscilation.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: For example, $f(x) = \frac{2x}{x+1}\sin x + x(1 + \sin x)$.